# AFHTTPRequestOperation blocks UI

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I have the following code that fetches some data from a php script. I'm finding that it blocks the interface so that the progress indicator doesn't spin. 
Is there an easy way to send this to the background so that the UI is free to do whatever it needs? I was under the impression that using blocks would have achieved this but I was obviously wrong (learning Obj-C one step at a time!)

Thanks!

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        self.user.username, @"username",
                        self.user.password, @"password",
                        nil];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com"]];

    // Show animated progress indicator, etc    
[self enbleLoadingState:YES];

[client postPath:@"/en/api/login" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
    [self enbleLoadingState:NO];
    // Do stuff

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self enbleLoadingState:NO];
    // Show error
}];
```

Comment: This code should work, the request loads in the background. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: better subclass AFHTTPClient and make it a singleton class

Comment: @phix23 But it doesn't work :( In my php script I do a sleep(5) which waits for 5 seconds, and the progress indicator just stays there and I can't hit any other buttons on the UI. I'm using the latest Xcode and iOS SDK to date. This happens in the simulator as well as on an iPad first generation. I'm using ARC... I can't think of anything else that will shed any light on this. I will try subclassing the client as you said (I think I saw an example of this somewhere).

Comment: @phix23 I just made the AFHTTPClient into a singleton (the sample iOS app had one I could use with minor tweaks) and the problem remains, only the code is much cleaner now :) Any ideas?

Comment: I still don't know where the time is spent on the main thread, maybe in `enbleLoadingState:`? The method starting the request should return immediately. Test this by inserting a NSLog at the start and the end of the method and inside the success-block. The NSLog in the success-block should print at last.

Comment: Your suggestion works as expected (everything runs in the order you mention) and this led me to try something else: I stuck an activity indicator in the view (via IB and unhooked to any code) and this runs perfectly. The minute I hook it up as an IBOutlet it stops spinning while executing the block. I re-wrote the controller from scratch (it wasn't that big) and now everything works perfectly! I must have screwed something somewhere... phinx23 if you want you can copy your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the proper answer since it was what led me to solving it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work, the request loads in the background. The problem must be somewhere else.
I don't know where the time is spent on the main thread, maybe in `enbleLoadingState:`? The method starting the request should return immediately. Test this by inserting a NSLog at the start and the end of the method and inside the success-block. The NSLog in the success-block should print out last.